# How to set two buttons to turn on/off vibration on iOS ?

Tags: ios, vibration

How to set two buttons to turn on/off vibration on iOS ?

This is what I was trying to do:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL vibeIsOn;

- (IBAction)startVibrating:(id)sender {
dispatch_queue_t vibeQueue = dispatch_queue_create("vibe", NULL);
dispatch_sync(vibeQueue, ^{

    for (;!self.vibeIsOn;)
    {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

    }
});
dispatch_release(vibeQueue);}

- (IBAction)stopVibrating:(id)sender {
self.vibeIsOn = YES;
AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);}
```

Unfortunately, when I press the "**staring vibrating**" button, it just can not jump out of the for loop, but I did put the for loop in a thread, right?

Help!!! Is anything wrong with this code?

Comment: what calls "`stopVibrating`"?  The same button that called "`startVibrating`"?

Comment: stopVibrating and startVibrating both are buttons on the view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dispatch the queue synchronously, so the calling thread waits until the execution finishes (which never happens because you for loop never stops). Use `dispatch_async` instead.

Comment: @JerryZhu In this case you should check the grey checkmark next to the answer to accept it as the correct one.

Comment: will it work if the vibration is turned off in the settings go iPhone

Comment: @madLokesh it's working in my case even if iPhone turned off the vibration

Comment: i was not using dispatch_queue earlier, now i added dispatch_queue but  i am still facing the same issue